# User copying correct anwers and pasting to same question

Tags: discussion

This guy is copying and pasting other answers on random questions, even before they get accepted but as soon they get upvoted.
I have nothing for blaming him, but I got curious, is there any default line of conduct in cases like this?

Comment: Should this question go to meta.stackexchange maybe?

Comment: I understand you do not want to disclose too much about that user, for fear the Meta effect ruins their life, but there is nothing we can do or discuss without at least a link to an occurrence of this problem.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033937/how-can-i-handle-no-spaces-in-phone-number-case-for-this-regex/29034182#comment46309715_29034182 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033649/if-and-or-multiple-statements-in-vba/29034243#29034243 and so on....

Comment: If a user is plagiarising (claiming other work as their own) you need to flag their post for moderator attention and explain, especially if there is a pattern.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for spotting the duplicate, I understand the issue with licensing could actually escalate in some cases; anyway I am too lazy to report stuff like this and will leave the pleasure to somebody else

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ: I'm sure people are already on the case. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters ahahah _"they've assigned four more detectives to the case, got us working in shifts." (cit.)_ Now I feel reluctant of having asked this, because most comments of that guy were actually very funny

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ: yeah, it's more a troll account than a reputation cheat. Still, should be dealt with just the same.

Comment: Thanks for the flags. I have educated this user as to the error of their ways.

Comment: @BradLarson: Where *educated* means *destroyed their account*? Or was it merged?